# I have to find an XML Element depending if there is a specific Element in that Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML-File:

```
<children xmi:type="notation:General" xmi:id="1">
  <children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="2">
    <element xmi:type="uml:Package" href="krZQ"/>
  </children>
  <children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="3">
    <element xmi:type="uml:Package" href="wtFm"/>
  </children>
  <children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="4"/>
</children>
```

I want to find all `<children>` Elements that have `xmi:type="notation:Shape"` as their Attribute and also have an `<element>` Element as a branch in them.

So for this XML-File i want to find:

```
<children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="2">
  <element xmi:type="uml:Package" href="krZQ"/>   
</children>

and

<children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="3">
  <element xmi:type="uml:Package" href="wtFm"/>   
</children>
```

But thats not all yet. I would also like to be able to only find a specific `<children>` Element.

For Example: I also want to be able to find only the `<children>` Element, which has the `<element>` Element in them with the `href="wtFm`.

I hope the Question is somewhat clear.

Comment: You have a tree structure and want to find a branch of the tree that contains a specific object.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree.  I usually do this with a recursive algorithm.

Comment: It would really help if you could reduce your XML to a *minimal* example that demonstrates what you're interested in - and use backticks to escape XML in the regular text... at the moment it's very hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on LINQ to XML and XPath.

If you need to find anything else, just modify the XPath expression.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\KeepGoing.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    
    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    nsManager.AddNamespace("notation", "http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.3/notation");   

    XElement result = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("/notation:Diagram//children[element/@href='NotionTestSysMLSync.uml#__SxgIJA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ']", nsManager);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
<children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="__S3mwJA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" type="Package_Shape_CN" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI">
  <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="__S3mwpA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" type="Package_NameLabel_CN" />
  <children xmi:type="notation:BasicCompartment" xmi:id="__S4N0JA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" type="Package_PackagedElementCompartment_CN">
    <styles xmi:type="notation:TitleStyle" xmi:id="__S4N0ZA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" />
    <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="__S4N0pA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" />
  </children>
  <element xmi:type="uml:Package" href="NotionTestSysMLSync.uml#__SxgIJA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" />
  <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="__S3mwZA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ" x="234" y="48" height="221" />
</children>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string PATTERN = "NotionTestSysMLSync.uml#__SxgIJA-Ee6PYKPEUWkrZQ";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            List<XElement> results = Search(root, PATTERN);
        }

        static public List<XElement> Search(XElement parent, string pattern)
        {
            List<XElement> results = null;
            foreach (XElement child in parent.Elements("children"))
            {
                XElement element = child.Element("element");
                if (element != null)
                {
                    string href = (string)element.Attribute("href");
                    if (href == pattern)
                    {
                        results = new List<XElement>();
                        results.Add(child);
                        break;
                    }

                }

                results = Search(child, pattern);
                if (results != null)
                {
                    results.Insert(0, child);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That almost works. But right now it finds and saves all parent <children> Elements. But I only want to save the one that is only 1 Level higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: You can get desired results from my code.  The results is a list of three items.  All you need to do is to take index 1 and 2.